# How do I get the even/odd number check to print the results?

Tags: javascript, html

I got something to print but it is not the proper answer. Right now I am just getting `"[object HTMLFormElement] is a Odd number"` no matter what number I enter weather it is even or odd.

```js
function isEvenorOdd(num, form) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is a Even number`
        console.log(`${num} is a Even number`)
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is a Odd number`
        console.log(`${num} is a Odd number`)
    }
}
```

```html
Check if numbers are even or odd:
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Check" 
onclick="isEvenorOdd (this.form);">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You're passing `this.form` in to the `num` argument, not a numerical value. I'm guessing you meant to use `this.value` instead

Comment: also if you fix that, it will print `check is a Odd number` because you set the `value` attr of your button as `check` and since the `onclick` in on the button, then `this.value` will only get you the value set on the button, not the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code

- `isEvenorOdd` function - you have two marameters `num` and `form`. But when you call the function in the `onclick` attr, you are only passing the form element (`this.form`) not the input field.
- You are not actually getting the value from the input field
- Your input field has no ID which the JS cant determine or get the value.

**Here is a working example - fairly straight forward:**

```js
    function isEvenorOdd() {
        let num = document.getElementById('num').value;

        // Check if number is valid
        if (isNaN(num)) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Please enter a valid number`;
            return;
        }

        num = parseInt(num);

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is an Even number`
            console.log(`${num} is an Even number`)
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is an Odd number`
            console.log(`${num} is an Odd number`)
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div>Check if numbers are even or odd:</div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="num">
        <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="isEvenorOdd();">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

**Big Int Example**: for use case **11111111111111111** and **11111111111111112**

```js
    function isEvenorOdd() {
        let num = document.getElementById('num').value;

        // Check if number is valid
        if (isNaN(num)) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Please enter a valid number`;
            return;
        }

        num = BigInt(num);

        if (num % 2n == 0n) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is an Even number`
            console.log(`${num} is an Even number`)
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is an Odd number`
            console.log(`${num} is an Odd number`)
        }
    }
```

```html
    Check if numbers are even or odd:
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="num">
        <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="isEvenorOdd();">
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: *Your input field has no ID which the JS cant determine or get the value.* that is not true, in the original code, you can access the `type="text"` input element using something like `num.elements[0]`. There is no need for an ID.

Comment: Just keep in mind that too big numbers can fool output for example try it with 11111111111111111 it's gona round it up to 11111111111111112 and say its even :)

Comment: @Titus - i just used their example. @Damian - for that i would suggest using         `num = BigInt(num);` to circumvent the js `Number` type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `onclick` function on your HTML it is much better to use [**eventListeners**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('input[type=button]');;//get the button element
const result = document.getElementById('result')
//addEventListener to the button
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let num = document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value;//get the input text only on each button press to ge tthe value every time
   //Number() to convert it to a number then compare, also validate if number is NaN
  if(!isNaN(num)){
    num = Number(num);
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      result.textContent = `${num} is an Even number`;
    } else {
      result.textContent = `${num} is an Odd number`;
    }
  } else {
    result.textContent = `your input "${num}" is not a number, plz try again`;
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  Check if numbers are even or odd:
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Check">
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Also if you are going to change the text of an element only then it is much better in terms of performance to use `textContent` than `innerHTML`.

Also you have to validate if the user actually typed numbers, since it's an input text, they can type whatever they want, not necesarily a number so. If they type something like `Foo` then you have to validate with `isNaN()` when you convert it to a number with `Number()` if that returns `NaN` then that means that he didn't type a number so therefore it can't be converted with `Number()` and you can return something like `${num} is not a number`

Answer (score -1):

As said, you are passing the form object and not the numeric value of the field. you need to get the text input, get its value, parse it to int, and then call `isEvenorOdd`:

```js
function isEvenorOdd(num, form) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is a Even number`
        console.log(`${num} is a Even number`)
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${num} is a Odd number`
        console.log(`${num} is a Odd number`)
    }
}
```

```html
Check if numbers are even or odd:
<form>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Check" 
onclick="isEvenorOdd(parseInt(this.form.querySelector('input[type=text]').value));">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```